# django messages for a successfully delete,add or edit item

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, web

I have started using django messages for creating items.
It works great for creating adding a new item.

but.. I want to have functions for each action - 
delete,create,edit ( I have different buttons for each)
I have only post function.. it really confuse me when I try to create a message that the item has been deleted successfuly.. how can I know a delete was submitted and not post? since everything goes through post function.

The PostEdit and Delete don't have the "request" that it requires for messages.

So for now I h ave only messages.succuess that runs everytime I create a server.
I want to have a different message for delete, edit, create and same for errors.

Does anyone have a clue?

index.html -

```
{% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
```

views.py -

```
# Create your views here.

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, UpdateView, DeleteView, CreateView
from DevOpsWeb.forms import HomeForm
from DevOpsWeb.models import serverlist
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from simple_search import search_filter
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib import messages

class HomeView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'serverlist.html'


    def get(self, request):

        form = HomeForm()
        query = request.GET.get("q")
        posts = serverlist.objects.all()

        forms = {}

        if query:
            posts = serverlist.objects.filter(Q(ServerName__icontains=query) | Q(Owner__icontains=query) | Q(Project__icontains=query) | Q(Description__icontains=query) | Q(IP__icontains=query) | Q(ILO__icontains=query) | Q(Rack__icontains=query))
        else:
            posts = serverlist.objects.all()
        for post in posts:
            forms[post.id] = HomeForm(instance=post)
        args = {'form' : form,'forms': forms, 'posts' : posts}

        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self,request):
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        posts = serverlist.objects.all()
        forms = {}


        if form.is_valid(): # Checks if validation of the forms passed
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            messages.success(request,'{0} has been added successfully!'.format(post.ServerName))

            return redirect('serverlist')
        messages.error(request,'Servername is required, please refresh the page and try again.')
        for post in posts:
            forms[post.id] = HomeForm(instance=post)
        args = {'form' : form, 'forms': forms, 'posts' : posts}

        return render(request, self.template_name,args)


class PostDelete(DeleteView):
    model = serverlist
    success_url = reverse_lazy('serverlist')

class PostEdit(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'serverlist.html'
    model = serverlist
    form_class = HomeForm
    #messages.success(request,"The server has been edited successfully")
    #fields = ['ServerName','Owner','Project','Description','IP','ILO','Rack','Status']

    success_url = reverse_lazy('serverlist')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the delete method in the deleteview for changing the message type:

```
class PostDelete(SuccessMessageMixin, DeleteView):
    model = serverlist
    success_url = reverse_lazy('serverlist')
    success_message = "Object deleted"
    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        messages.warning(self.request, self.success_message)
        return super(PostDelete, self).delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

You can do the same by overriding the update method for UpdateView.

Comment: Works great!
The only thing that I'm worried now is how I put the actual server name in the message...
In the post function I could use '{0} has been added successfully!'.format(post.ServerName))
But here I can't use post.ServerName..
Plus, Do you know how to bold the servername? since it's not html and I don't have <b>,<strong> in django?

Comment: For clarification: For other class-based views, the `SuccessMessageMixin` displays the `success_message` without having to override the `delete` method. However, for `DeleteView`s this is not the case, and this needs to be overridden -- see https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21926.

Answer (score 1):

```
class PostEdit(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'serverlist.html'
    model = serverlist
    form_class = HomeForm
    #messages.success(request,"The server has been edited successfully")
```

You can't call `messages.success` in the class definition like that. The call has to go in a method like `post` or `form_valid`.

The messages framework has a `SuccessMessageMixin` which you might find useful. You add the mixin to each view, and set `success_message`:

```
class PostDelete(SuccessMessageMixin, DeleteView):
    model = serverlist
    success_url = reverse_lazy('serverlist')
    success_message = "Object deleted"
```

See the docs on [adding messages to class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-messages-in-class-based-views) for more info.

Comment: Do you know how I can add the actual servername inside like I did in the post? post.servername not working here since the class doesn't know what it is

Comment: The docs I linked to show how you can do this. You can use string interpolation if the value is in the form data, or you can override `get_success_message`.